# Text rendering on DirectX 11 without Textures

Tags: fonts, c++-cli, directx-11

I have a c++/cli game framework based on DirectX11 and I want to draw a text on my window but on every example that I found people is reading the font from a texture that as .dds format, I want to draw without using a Texture, anyone know how?

Answer (score 1):

There's a nice open source library that does this, [FW1FontWrapper](http://fw1.codeplex.com/)

Using it for my engine and it does the job quite nicely.

Please note that if you target windows phone it's unlikely to work, for Desktop/RT it should be fine tho.

Comment: I'm adding and using the FW1FontWrapper library on my project but after compiling and testing on my C# application I'm getting the Exception FIleLoadException was unhandled, make sure that the file is a valid .NETframework assembly, you can help me? :\

Comment: What about Windows Phone?

Comment: FW1FontWrapper is not an assembly, it's a native library, so you need to do a small bridge to access it as managed.

Answer (score -1):

you could do it using [ID3DXFont](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb173962%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Is not DirectX9 ID3DXFont??

Comment: yes containded, but you would not need the .dds texture, you could draw it with color.

Comment: D3DX is no longer available.